# why conky and docky doesn't start automatically at lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, autostart, conky, docky

I installed Lubuntu 13.10 and want to run installed conky and docky after booting whenever I lunch lubuntu.

I installed next:

> sudo apt-get install xcompmgr

Once installed, I put the command to autostart xcompmgr whenever Lubuntu starts:

> gksudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart

Here is content of my autostart file:

```
@xcompmgr -n
@conky
```

But this doesn't start automatically. Any suggestions?

How to solve this trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lubuntu 13.10, edit `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`. Add the appropriate commands on separate lines to the end of the existing file. If such a file doesn't exist, create it with Leafpad or nano.

Note that `@` should *not* be present at the start of each line.